# Button To Flash

Tags: java, android, while-loop, android-button

Hi im trying to get a button to flash, I have tried to change the background with a loop, but not having much luck any suggestions thanks

```
int count = 0;
while (count < 10000) {  // test: boolean test within (..)
    if (count % 2 != 0) { 
        helpt.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Blue));
    } 
    else { 
        helpt.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Red));
    } 
    count = count + 1;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will change the colour every one second:

```
int count = 0; //Declare as instance variable    
Activity activity; //Declare as instance variable 

//Inside onCreate()
activity = this;
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (count < 10000) {
                        if (count % 2 != 0) {
                            helpt.setBackgroundColor(getResources()
                                    .getColor(android.R.color.black));
                        } else {
                            helpt.setBackgroundColor(getResources()
                                    .getColor(android.R.color.white));
                        }
                        count = count + 1;
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply.. im getting an error on the count = count + 1 line .. the following error The final local variable count cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type

Comment: got it working needed to declare the variable on top.. thanks Shivam :-)

Comment: Yep, I wrote in the comments to declare as instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have any form of delay, of course you wouldn't see it flash. It will run through that loop very quickly. Also for standards you should be using a for loop, not a while. For is explicityly for when you know how many times you are going to run.

Comment: any suggestions please